# Can't call an overloaded constructor in Scala

Tags: scala

My code looks like this:

```
val people = Array(Array("John", "25"), Array("Mary", "22"))
val headers = Seq("Name", "Age")
val myTable = new Table(people, headers)
```

I get this syntax error:

```
overloaded method constructor Table with alternatives:
    (rows: Int,columns: Int)scala.swing.Table 
    <and>
    (rowData: Array[Array[Any]],columnNames: Seq[_])scala.swing.Table
    cannot be applied to
    (Array [Array[java.lang.String]], Seq[java.lang.String])
```

I don't see why the second alternative isn't used. Is there a distinction between "Any" and "_" that's tripping me up here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As Kim already said, you need to make your array covariant in his element type, because Scala's Arras are not covariant like Java's/C#'s.

This code will make it work for instance:

```
class Table[+T](rowData: Array[Array[T]],columnNames: Seq[_])
```

This just tells the compiler that `T` should be covariant (this is similar to Java's `? extends T` or C#'s `out T`).

If you need more control about what types are allowed and which not, you can also use:

```
class Table[T <: Any](rowData: Array[Array[T]],columnNames: Seq[_])
```

This will tell the compiler that `T` can be any subtype of `Any` (which can be changed from `Any` to the class you require, like `CharSequence` in your example).

Both cases work the same in this scenario:

```
scala> val people = Array(Array("John", "25"), Array("Mary", "22"))
people: Array[Array[java.lang.String]] = Array(Array(John, 25), Array(Mary, 22))   

scala> val headers = Seq("Name", "Age")
headers: Seq[java.lang.String] = List(Name, Age)

scala> val myTable = new Table(people, headers)
myTable: Table[java.lang.String] = Table@350204ce
```

**Edit:** If the class in question is not in your control, declare the type you want explicitly like this:

```
val people: Array[Array[Any]] = Array(Array("John", "25"), Array("Mary", "22"))
```

---

**Update**

This is the source code in question:

```
// TODO: use IndexedSeq[_ <: IndexedSeq[Any]], see ticket [#2005][1]
def this(rowData: Array[Array[Any]], columnNames: Seq[_]) = {
```

I wonder if someone forgot to remove the workaround, because #2005 is fixed since May 2011 ...

Comment: I think this is assuming that Table is my class. The Table I need is scala.swing.Table. Also, asInstanceOf doesn't seem to help.

Comment: Thanks, the explicit typing does the job. (I thought I had tried that earlier but I guess I was using old object code.)
I see I have rows and columns reversed--okay, that's easy--and my headers don't show up. Not critical for what I'm doing, though.

Answer (score 3):

`Array[Array[String]]` is *not* a subtype of `Array[Array[Any]]` because Array's type parameter is not covariant. You should read up on [co-, contra- and invariance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariance_and_contravariance_%28computer_science%29). This should fix it:

```
val people = 
  Array(Array("John", "25"), Array("Mary", "22")).asInstanceOf[Array[Array[Any]]
```

Comment: It's true I don't understand those very well. However,
    val people: Array[Array[Any]] = Array(Array("John", "25"), Array("Mary", "22"))
doesn't give an error message.
I guess I should have asked: "How can I fix my code?"
Thanks!