# Creating a Java Object in Scala

Tags: java, scala, class, apache-spark

I have a Java class "Listings". I use this in my Java MapReduce job as below:

```
public void map(Object key, Text value, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
Listings le = new Listings(value.toString());
...
}
```

I want to run the same job on Spark. So, I am writing this in Scala now. I imported the Java class:

```
import src.main.java.lists.Listings
```

I want to create a Listings object in Scala. I am doing this:

```
val file_le = sc.textFile("file// Path to file")
Listings lists = new Listings(file_le)
```

I get an error:

> value lists is not a member of object src.main.java.lists.Listings

What is the right way to do this?

Comment: Never worked on Scala. That being said, try changing the import to `import lists.Listings`

Comment: Thanks @bot . Import works fine. The next line is what I am talking about.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on what you've said, I think you may be forgetting the differences between Scala syntax and Java syntax.

Try this:

```
val lists: Listings = new Listings(SomeString)
```

Please note that specifying the type in Scala is completely optional.  Also, use a var if you're going to be changing the value of `lists`.

The way you have it, Scala is trying to interpret it by its ability to call methods/access values of an object without the '.', so you're actually telling Scala this:

```
Listings.lists = new Listings(SomeString)
```

Comment: Thanks @soong . Now I get this error:    error: overloaded method constructor Listings with alternatives:
  (x$1: String)src.main.java.lists.Listings.                                                             cannot be applied to (org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[String])

Comment: I'm afraid I'm not entirely certain how to fix that part, as my knowledge on using Java from within Scala is rather limited.  Doing a bit of research, it sounds like it has something to do with the parameterized types in use.  These links might help you, though you might want to ask a second question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8041105/xml-creation-error-overloaded-method-constructor-unprefixedattribute-with-alt  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6735698/cant-call-an-overloaded-constructor-in-scala

Comment: Thank you @soong. I did     Listings lists = new Listings(file_le.toString). Now I get ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1. I get the same error when I try to pass any string. What could be wrong?

Comment: Yes. Not toString. Sorry. Used mkString. I get java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1 error

Comment: I was splitting the input using a wrong character. I got it working!                val lists: Listings = new Listings(SomeString)    works now.